# How to use HTC Desire and Eclipse on Ubuntu 10.4 to test Android Apps?

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

If I try to use my HTC Desire to test Apps I'm developing with Eclipse, then in the screen where I can choose the emulators and connected devices, it is only listed as unknown and a few question marks.

I read that on Windows you need HTC Sync respectively the drivers in this program, but how can I solve this problem on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you never set up the udev rule in linux, the usb connection will not work correctly. There is a tutorial in the official document:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up

Answer (score 0):

For ubutnu you need to add a rule
in

> /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

make the file executable
then add this file to the document

> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"